# How to bring a Windows Form on top?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a windows form application in C#. This application shows some text on the Form when a special kind of external event occurs (For example suppose that I want to write "Mouse is on upper line" on form when in the mouse's position y=0). I need to bring the Form to top of every other window when the event occurs.

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it more clearer but it still is unclear, what do you mean "mouse's position y=0"

Comment: you have to use mdiparent and mdichild to different classes and show them in front , activate or whatever.

Comment: @Sayse: It is not important at all. I just wanted to bring an example of an event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in you form class:

```
public void BringToTop()
{
    //Checks if the method is called from UI thread or not
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(BringToTop));
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //Keeps the current topmost status of form
        bool top = TopMost;
        //Brings the form to top
        TopMost = true;
        //Set form's topmost status back to whatever it was
        TopMost = top;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it really works. Thank you.

Comment: I got help from another person and know I am just passing it to you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](http://blog.jorgearimany.com/2010/10/win32-setforegroundwindow-equivalent-in.html) you can simply do `form.Activate();`

P.S.
You may find [this information](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bf3117f8-d83d-4b00-8e4f-7398b559a2dd/c-bring-windows-form-to-front?forum=winforms) useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
yourForm.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: How would you set it true from an external event?

Comment: It won't work if the window is minimized.

Comment: It gives me run-time error. From exceptions message, I think I can not change the value from another thread.